# sourceMappingURL in output Angular 9 SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, nrwl-nx

I have setup SSR for Angular 9 project. I am using NX workspace with Angular CLI for my application. When I run the application with **serve-ssr** option, and when I open the page and check a source code, I see **sourceMappingURL** output in it.

angular.json has already set **"sourceMap": false** but it is still producing **sourceMappingURL** in output.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You do have sourceMaps to false for both front and ssr targets, right?

Comment: yes ... please check the screenshots of my angular.json file